# How to create a function import/stored procedure with EDM that includes reference entities

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

Does anybody know how to create a function import in an Entity Data Model that returns a collection of entity types that also includes the reference types. For instance, in LINQ to entities you can use the .Include() method to load a certain referenced entity from the DB. I have a stored procedure that returns data from two tables and I want to populate both entity objects from this stored procedure, but when I step through the wizard to create the function import, it only gives the option of creating collections of one entity type at a time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know it is not supported. Stored procedures in EFv4 can return only single result set which is directly mapped to single selected entity type. Relations are not populated.

You must populate entities manually if want to load relations as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you mean without using a stored procedure? Or getting the data table using a stored procedure and then running through the data and populating the objects then? Are there any considerations I need to take into account when populating the objects? Like how to register it with the ObjectContext/objectStateManager?

Comment: I mean running stored procedure and populating objects yourselves. Registering to state manager can be tricky. You need to call `Attach` for each top level entity which is not already attached.